# Extreme Citrix Desktop Lag/Latency

Tags: lag, latency, citrix

My wife and I work identical jobs, remotely from our work-supplied laptops.  She experiences extreme lag while in the Citrix desktop environment, and I do not.  It is extremely difficult to do her job when there is a delay to start typing, delay when moving and clicking her mouse, delay when moving program windows around the screen, delay when minimizing and maximizing program windows, etc.  Some information:

- Her ICA Round Trip Time (RTT) is around 1,850ms; mine is 60ms.
- Her ICA Latency is around 8,370ms; mine is 75ms.
- Both our laptops are on a wired connection through the same router.
- The symptoms are not present when no one else is logged in, after hours.
- Her laptop has never experienced any issues with lag, only the Citrix desktop.
- The lag is present when she shares her screen, but disappears when our IT department assumes control during the screen sharing session.
- If it matters, our laptops run Windows 10 and the Citrix desktop runs Windows Server 2012 R2.

Attempted fixes include:

- Hooking her laptop up to my connection.
- Changing her ethernet cord.
- Changing physical port she is connected to at the router.
- Connecting her laptop to WiFi instead of ethernet.
- Changing her laptop.
- Changing the dock the laptop plugs into.
- Manually upgrading all the drivers and software on her laptop.
- Having her log into her Citrix environment from my laptop
- Disabling mouse shadows in the Citrix desktop environment.

After a month of troubleshooting, IT are blaming our internet connection.  I have a half dozen other co-workers who are similarly affected, and IT is also giving up and blaming their internet.  I am hoping someone on this site will have some suggestions for local or server settings IT can tweak to try and resolve the issue.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd do a traceroute towards both yours and your wife's citrix server (yours just for reference). Considering your ping response, I bet there's a spike at the end of her route. My main suspect however would be that the citrix server is way overloaded, not sure how to diagnose that one without admin access to said server.

Comment: I will do that and report my findings in a few hours.  Thank you for steering me in the correct direction.

Comment: At the very least the comparative traceroutes to similar services will rule out the home connection, and give you some ammo to slap your wife's IT helpdesk around with :)

Comment: no further findings??